# select query to push null values to last column in address lines

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a query to select the address lines so that the null values should be pushed to last columns. For example if the table has below data

```
ID, line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6
1   null   test2  test3  test4  test5  test6
2   test1  test2  test3  test4  test5  test6
3   null   null   null   null   test5  test6
4   test1  test2  test3  null   test5  test6
```

Output of the query should be as follow

```
ID, line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6
1   test2  test3  test4  test5  test6  null
2   test1  test2  test3  test4  test5  test6
3   test5  test6  null   null   null   null
4   test1  test2  test3  test5  test6  null
```

I tried to concatenate the values with a delimiter by eliminating the nulls and then split the values again, but I am having difficulty in splitting the values back as the actual data contains characters which are not xml supported. Is there a easy way to do this with out creating functions to split? Below works when there are no characters in values which cause cast to xml fail

```
SELECT
  ISNULL(Line1 + '|', '')
+ ISNULL(Line2 + '|', '')
+ ISNULL(Line3 + '|', '')
 + ISNULL(Line4 + '|', '')
  + ISNULL(Line5 + '|', '')
   + ISNULL(Line6 , '')  as tmpaddr 
FROM #addr1

SELECT DISTINCT id,
S.a.value('(/H/r)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS line1,
S.a.value('(/H/r)[2]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS line2,
S.a.value('(/H/r)[3]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS line3,
S.a.value('(/H/r)[4]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS line4,
S.a.value('(/H/r)[5]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS line5,
S.a.value('(/H/r)[6]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS line6
FROM
(
SELECT *,CAST (N'<H><r>' + REPLACE(tmpaddr , '|', '</r><r>')  + '</r></H>'      AS XML) AS [vals]
FROM #addr ) d 
CROSS APPLY d.[vals].nodes('/H/r') S(a)
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me assume you are using SQL Server, based on the syntax conventions.

You can do what you want with `cross apply` and aggregation:

```
SELECT a.id, t.*
FROM #addr1 a CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN line END) as line1,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN line END) as line2,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN line END) as line3,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 4 THEN line END) as line4,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 5 THEN line END) as line5,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 6 THEN line END) as line6
      FROM (SELECT num, line, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY num) as seqnum
            FROM (VALUES (1, a.line1),
                         (2, a.line2),
                         (3, a.line3),
                         (4, a.line4),
                         (5, a.line5),
                         (6, a.line6)
                 ) v(num, line)
            WHERE line IS NOT NULL
           ) t
     ) t;
```